# SignalR on HTTPS

Tags: exception, https, signalr

I am trying to use SignalR client side libraries on HTTPS server. It works fine on normal server but on HTTPS server, it is throwing an exception.

try

{
...
hubConnection = new HubConnection(signalUrl);

proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("SignalRConnect");

hubConnection.Start().Wait(); // throws an exception at this line

...
 }

catch (Exception ex) {

I am getting exception - "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

}

Does anybody has an idea how to configure client side SignalR?

Thank you in advanced.

Medha

Answer (score 0):

If your server requires custom client certificates then you can use SignalR 1.1 beta to add an  x509certificate to the connection before the request is made.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I removed the code of creating proxy from the controller and add code on client side and get context of the hub from controller code.

var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext();

and use hubContext for client notification.